# Telling the browser not to execute html code embedded in a textarea

Tags: html

I have an embed code and I use it to allow users to embed music into their own websites.  The problem, however, is that I can not just show the code in a textarea b/c the code consists of "" and the w3 code check says that this is invalid.  Is there any code that I can enter to just declare this as text that the browser does not execute?  I can't figure it out.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [HTML entities](http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html/extras/entities.html).

- For `"` use `&quot;`
- For `<` use `&lt;`
- For `>` use `&gt;`

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks.  I will accept the answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: @Eggo apparently you don't =p

Comment: Sorry about that.  I got a bit sidetracked.  I fixed it and checked it off.  I am very sorry for the 2 day delay.